# How to add two dataframes together based on a column using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two dataframes that I want to summurize in another.

```
df1 =

authorId,quest1, quest2, quest3, ...
1, xxx, xxx, xxx, ...
2, xxx, xxx, xxx, ...
3, xxx, xxx, xxx, ...
...
```

and

```
df2 =

authorId,answer1, answer2, answer3, ...
1, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
2, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
3, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
...
```

I would like to have

```
df3 = 

authorId,quest1, quest2, quest3, answer1, answer2, answer3, 
1, xxx, xxx, xxx, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
2, xxx, xxx, xxx, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
3, xxx, xxx, xxx, yyy, yyy, yyy, ...
...
```

I already tried to merge or join (on inner, left, right, outer) but it doesn't work as expected.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='authorId', how='inner')
```

When I try to join i got an error :

> You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to
>   proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: `pd.concat([df1.set_index('authorId'),df2.set_index('authorId'),axis=1])` try this

Comment: It doesn't work, i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @anky_91 suggestion using concat or convert the authorID column to int.

```
df1['authorId'] = df1['authorId'].astype(int)
df2['authorId'] = df2['authorId'].astype(int)
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='authorId', how='inner')
```

You can check the dataframe dtypes to see if the authorID column is the same type in both DFs.

```
df1.dtypes
df2.dtypes
```

Comment: As a quick addition to this: Often, an ID column which should be float64 or int type becomes object type because of one outlier value or typo, like "112A" or nan.

You may have to change those values or filter your dataframe if the `.astype(int)` also throws up an error.